# Ending Session when leaving a folder or certain urls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Is there anyway to unset or end a session when I leave a folder on the website, such as /maps/ or just ending it when i'm not un certain urls?

Currently I'm using:

```
<script>
$(window).on('unload', function() {

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('ajax_data', 22);

    navigator.sendBeacon('resources/ajax/unload.php', fd);
});

</script>
```

That calls to this code

```
<?php require_once("../config.php");
 ignore_user_abort(true);
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
 $time = date("H:i:s");
 $date = date("Y/m/d");
 $query = "uknown";
 $session_id = session_id();
 $session_prev = $_SESSION['prev'];
 $ip = $_SESSION['ip'];

 $sql = query("INSERT INTO navigated (navigated_from, navigated_to, 
 navigated_date, navigated_time, session_id, session_ip) VALUES ( 
 '$session_prev', '$query',  '$date', '$time', '$session_id', '$ip' 
  )");


 if (!isset($_SESSION['ended'])) {
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
 $_SESSION['ended'] = date("H:i:s");

 }

 $session_end = $_SESSION['ended'];
 $session_start = $_SESSION['started'];
 $session_date = $_SESSION['date'];
 $session_clicks = $_SESSION['clicks'];
 $sql2 = query("INSERT INTO session_time (session_id, 
 session_start, session_end, session_date, session_clicks, 
 session_navigated, session_ip) VALUES ('$session_id', '$session_start', '$session_end', '$session_date', '$session_clicks',  '$query', '$ip')");

unset($_SESSION['ended']);
unset($_SESSION['date']);
unset($_SESSION['started']);
unset($_SESSION['clicks']);
session_regenerate_id();


?>
```

Ends Sessions as soon as i leave the page, or push an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, as per your requirement, I think you can write an unset_maps_session() function, that has all the requirements for unsetting /maps/ folder session.

Write a common function, for example, common_tasks(), which will be called from each and every file in your project. 
The responsibility of common_tasks() function is to identify tasks to be done on that url. 
So you can do a regular expression check on the url to find out what tasks you need to carry out.

```
function common_tasks() {
    // Carry out regular expression checks on the $_SERVER['URI'] parameter
    //Suppose maps_maps_url_not_found is a boolean variable that is true if the current URL
    //is not a maps URL. 

    if(matched_maps_url_not_found) {
        unset_maps_session();
    }

}
```